# finding the area of triangle

Tags: triangles, area

its an 8th standard question . but i m unable to solve it. please help
Question " the perimeter of a triangle is 84m . the sides are in the ration 13:14:15 . find the area . "

(answer should come this === area = 336 square meter)

what i had tried is this.
$$s = \frac{13+14+15}2 = 21$$

$$Area = \sqrt{(21(21-13)\times(21-14)\times(21-15))}$$

```
Area = 84             not correct dont know where i am wrong
```

Comment: If the sides are in $13:14:15$ and the perimeter is $84$ m, what are the lengths of sides?

Comment: i had provided all whats given in question.

Comment: If the sides can be written as $13k$, $14k$ and $15k$ (all in metres) and they add up to $84$ m, what are the lengths of sides?

Comment: i had mentioned the exact question now.

Comment: it is given that sides ratio is $13:14:15$ which is quite different from considering that sides are of that length

Comment: If the sides can be written as $13k$, $14k$ and $15k$ (all in metres) and they add up to $84$ m, what is the value of $k$?

Answer (score 3):

Since the ratio of sides are in $13:14:15$, let the three sides be $13k$, $14k$ and $15k$ in ascending order.

Now the 3 sides add up to a perimeter length of $84$ m, so

$$\begin{align*}
13k + 14k + 15k =& 84 \text{ m}\\
k =& 2 \text{ m}
\end{align*}$$

And so the three sides are $26$ m, $28$ m and $30$ m respectively. Now use Heron's formula to find the area.

(Hint: you should confirm that $s$ is half of perimeter)